# Русские символы в ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Код "сервера":

```cs
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей же чаю.");
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Но "сервер" выхлопнул не то, что мне нужно:
[image: скриншот выхлопа сервера]

Как заставить ASP.Net Core отправлять русские символы?

Comment: Кодировка файла случайно не windows-1251 ?

Comment: @SultanovShamil UTF-8

Comment: В html ответа должно быть `<meta charset="utf-8">`, посмотрите этот тег, он есть почти на каждом сайте в исходнике страницы, а у вас наверняка нет.

Comment: @aepot это не сайт, это API.

Comment: Скорее всего браузер автоматом не ту кодировку определил. Если вручную переключить на UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в заголовки кодировку:

```
endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
{
    context.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Или так, можно было получить доступ к свойству ContentType объекта HttpResponse напрямую, а не через заголовки:

```
response.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
```

Тоже самое, что и в ответе выше, только через обращение напрямую к свойству ContentType, а не индексатор:

```
response.Headers.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
```

Comment: Вряд ли хорошая идея делать это в каждом методе.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders;

namespace Mywebsite2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime.
        // Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.TextEncoderSettings = new System
                    .Text.Encodings.Web
                    .TextEncoderSettings(System.Text.Unicode.UnicodeRanges.All);
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime.
        // Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days.
                // You may want to change this for production scenarios,
                // see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

WebEncoderOptions добавлял я - без этой штуки в браузере были кракозяблики вместо русских букв, английский отображался нормально.